# How many equilibrium solutions does this system of differential equations have?

Tags: differential

Am I correct to assume that this system of differential equations only has one equilibrium $(I_{1}, I_{2}, Q_{1}, Q_{2})$, namely: $(0,0,0,0)$ ? Would we also then say this is a stable solution?

$$
\frac{d Q_{1}}{d t} = I_{1} \\
\frac{d Q_{2}}{d t} = I_{2} \\
\frac{d I_{1}}{d t} = \frac{\frac{0.2 \, * \, 10^{-6}}{10^{-7}} \, * Q_{2} - \frac{L}{10^{-7}} \, * \, Q_{1}}{{L}^2 \, - \, 0.04 \, * \, 10^{-12}} \\
\frac{d I_{1}}{d t} = \frac{\frac{0.2 \, * \, 10^{-6}}{10^{-7}} \, * Q_{1} - \frac{L}{10^{-7}} \, * \, Q_{2}}{{L}^2 \, - \, 0.04 \, * \, 10^{-12}} \\
Q_{1}(0) = 0.2 \\
Q_{2}(0) = 0 \\
I_{1}(0) = 0 \\
I_{2}(0) = 0
$$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that: $1 \, * \, 10^{-6} \leq \, L \leq 30 \, * \, 10^{-6}$

Answer (score 1):

Define $$x =\begin{bmatrix}
I_1\\
I_2\\
Q_1\\
Q_2\end{bmatrix}$$

and write your system of equations as $$ \frac{dx}{dt} = A x, $$ where $A$ is a coefficient matrix. If $A$ is invertible, then the zero solution is the only possible solution of $Ax=0$. Otherwise, $\frac{dx}{dt} =0$ may have other solutions, all in the null-space of $A$. These solutions are strictly stable iff $A$ is a Hurwitz matrix, i.e., all its eigenvalues have negative real parts. So for a given value of $L$ you may check the eigenvalues of $A$ and see whether the zero solution is the only stable solution. It may be quite tricky to prove that the system is stable for all values of $L$, though Gershgoring’s circles might help.